# Is it possible to use window.performance.memory in headless chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, performance-testing

I want to use window.performance.memory to measure if I have any memory leaks in my headless chrome tests.

**In Tests:**

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        $('body').append(initHtml);
        console.log(window.performance.memory)
    });
```

Results in:`MemoryInfo {}`

**In dev console:**

```
console.log(window.performance.memory)
```

Results in:
`MemoryInfo {totalJSHeapSize: 27600000, usedJSHeapSize: 16100000, jsHeapSizeLimit: 1530000000}`

**My Karma.conf includes this:**

```
browsers: ['Chrome_with_memory_tests'],
customLaunchers: {
    Chrome_with_memory_tests: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--enable-precise-memory-info']
    }
},
```

Does anyone know why this may be? The window object is available since I can run other methods on it. Maybe I need another flag to enable this experimental feature?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance

Answer (score 0):

`window.performance.memory`'s properties are non-enumerable

If you want to see them, you may use something like:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(window.performance.memory, ['totalJSHeapSize', 'usedJSHeapSize', 'jsHeapSizeLimit']));

// Will output something like :
// {"totalJSHeapSize":239000000,"usedJSHeapSize":225000000,"jsHeapSizeLimit":2330000000}
```

And you do indeed have to enable the `enable-precise-memory-info` flag to have the values be correctly updated during program execution in headless mode.